# Can there be a single game of Chess which includes all the possible situations that may arise during Chess?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

First of all, I am sorry as there were some completely inappropriate posts posted by my account earlier. This happened because I forgot to log my account out from the computer in Net Cafe I last enetered and a devil used my account. Anyways, come to the question.

I guess that first of all, I have to calculate in numbers that how many different situations may arise in chess using permutation/combination/Probability and then check that how many different situations arises in the biggest possible game of chess (not w.r.t time). If the number of situations in the biggest game is equal to the number calculated earlier, then I can say that answer is Yes otherwise No. However this all stays a guess. Permutations/combinations/Probability: I am an amateur w.r.t to these theories. So, I would be grateful if anybody helps by giving the answer to my title in *yes* or *no* and then explain *why*.

Comment: Definitely not since pawns cannot move backwards

Comment: Can you be check-mated more than once?

Comment: No, because some games end with a king against king and rook, and other games end with a king against king and bishop, and there is no way to get from one to the other.

Comment: It would be good if downvoter explains what is the downvote for!

Comment: i dont think the question is "well-formed" enough to be meaningful.  For instance one possiblity is the white's queen bishop captured and another where the white's queen's bishop mates.  Or a game where the first move is one thing and another where the first move is something else.  Basically, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @fleablood that doesn't imply that question is not "well-meant".  By the way, your comment is a good answer so what is that you haven't got yet?

Comment: Anyway, I was talking about all possible situations that may arise without deviating FIDE rules.

Comment: I don't know what you consider a "situation".  Obviously you can't have "White is checkmated by a queen" as a situation and "black is checkmated by a rook" as another in the same game.  And obviously you can't have a situation A where a game consisted of exactly 57 precise moves in order and situation B where a game consisted of exactly 63 other moves in a precise order.  I really *don't* have the slightest idea what you mean.

Comment: ...or perhaps I assumed the answer was so utterly trivially obvious that I assumed you couldn't possibly have meant what you seemed to have mean.  (Situations include but not limited to: rook takes bishop; knight takes bishop, queen takes bishop, pawn takes bishop, bishop takes bishop, king... wait *five* bishops????)

Comment: Situation 1: white king castles on queen side.  Situation 2: white king castles on kings side.  Situation 3: white king moves before castling.

Comment: Yes @fleablood I suppose it is a silly question. But answers are nice anyway. ;)

Comment: It's not a silly question at all.  I just wasn't sure what you considered a "situation".  Is it possible to have a game during which every piece moves by every allowable rule. a pawn advances two initially, another pawn one initially, one pawn captures en passant, one pawn captures diagonally, on pawn is promoted, a king is check by each possible piece at one time, etc.  I think so.  That every possible capture happens?  Well  as there are 9^2 - 1 (All but K x K) possible ways 9 pieces can capture 9 others but only 32 pieces total. So no.

Comment: And calculating how many possible chess games there are is not a silly question at all and has been discussed and calculated.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood for supporting my question. I was saying it silly because, I should have thought somewhat rigorously before posting it and it would come to my mind that a pawn can not move backward, as others pointed out. This would immediately answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering the position of pawns it is easy to see that the answer to this question is no. Consider the following two positions:

[image]

[image]

Since once the A pawn has moved forward it will always be in a rank higher than 4, any game that has contained the first position cannot in the future contain the second and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

No and I'll give my reasons being to pawns. Assume you have one scenario where you move the pawn F2->F3. Then black moves a pawn or knight of any kind. Another possible scenario involves any of the other 7 pawns moving first while F2->F3 move could not have happened. Since you cannot move pawns backwards, you cannot have a game of chess where every single possible move is played.

Answer (score -2):

No, for the simple fact that the number of pieces on the board can only diminish or stay the same as the game goes on, and never go back up again (promotion still takes a piece of the board, namely a pawn), so once you reach a position where something has been captured, you have excluded the possibility of reaching a position where there are more pieces on the board; and since pawns can't move backwards, it is impossible to reach all positions prior to the capture.